# Empty Rectangles - Does the rule apply when the intersection takes place inside the box with the empty rectangle?

Tags: sudoku

The Empty Rectangles method is a strategy for solving Sudoku puzzles. I have seen the description of this strategy [here](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/Empty_Rectangles), I have the following question:

Is there a problem if the other end of the strong link and the ERI intersect **inside** the box which contains the empty rectangle?

For example if, in the 4th picture of the link above, Y was in A2 and Z in A8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 1]]

An Empty Rectangle means that in a box, a particular number is restricted to one row and one column. In this example on the linked page, the 8 in the top-right box is either in row C or column 8.

Either X or Y contains an 8. If Y contains the 8, then Z cannot. If X contains the 8, then the 8 in the top-right box cannot be in row C, so it must be in column 8. Then, Z also cannot contain 8. This is why this configuration allows Z to be eliminated.

If Y was at A2 and Z at A8 instead, this logic would not eliminate Z. If X is 8, then the 8 in the top-right box would have to be in column 8, but A8 is still a possible position for it.